# Slim App Session - session_start() works on one page but returns false on another

Tags: php, session, slim

I have a couple of different routes, both use sessions. Locally everything works just fine but on my server the session_start in the second code chunk below returns false... Nothing in the server error logs either.

**Excerpt from my file classes.php (works just fine)**

```
// Get all classes
$app->get('/classes', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app) {
    session_start();

    // Make sure the person is logged in.
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        echo '{"type": "danger","text": "You must be logged in to access this page."}';
    return;
    }

    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    ...
```

**Excerpt from my file profile.php (does not work, returns false on session_start() - files are in the same folder and referenced the same way)**

```
// Get Profile
$app->get('/profile', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app) {
    session_start();

    // Make sure the person is logged in.
    if( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        echo '{"type": "danger","text": "You must be logged in to access this page."}';
        return;
    }

    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    ...
```

Thanks for your help, any ideas  about how to debug would be great!

Comment: Move `session_start` to index.php before any output sent to browser.

Comment: Haha I swear I tried that and it didn't work. It did this time though! Thanks man! If you put the answer up I would be happy to accept it :)

Comment: I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `session_start()` call to `index.php` before any output sent to browser.